# How can I prevent horizontal scrolling when child elements extend beyond the width of the parent div?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, positioning

I've created a banner for my website that's made up of 3 iPhone images side-by-side, using background images and relative positioning for each. However, I'm having issues with the horizontal scrolling. That is even though the div's containing each iphone image extend beyond the width of the parent .content div, I don't want there to be a scrollbar when the overflow content isn't able to fit the browser width. Scrollbars should only be shown if the browser width is below 960px.

A similar effect is presently seen on [Apple's homepage](http://www.apple.com/), where the hand/wrist reside "outside" the website's container, but no horizontal scrollbars are visible unless the browser's width is below 990px wide.

I hope I've explained this clearly, please let me know if it's not clear.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="iphone-a"></div>
    <div id="iphone-b"></div>           
    <div id="iphone-c"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: visible;
    }

#iphone-a {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -306px;
    height: 657px;
    width: 590px;
    background: url(images/banner.png) 0px 0px;
    }

#iphone-b {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -545px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -732px;
    height: 319px;
    width: 590px;
    background: url(images/banner.png) 0px -658px;
    }

#iphone-c {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -864px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 144px;
    height: 319px;
    width: 590px;
    background: url(images/banner.png) 0px -658px;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
overflow-x: visible;
```

in .content to

```
overflow-x : hidden;
```

Edit : If that's not what u mean, and u just want visible to work correctly try using `overflow` instead of `overflow-x`

Comment: Changing the overflow to hidden hides the overflow content. I want the content to be visible, but only show a horizontal scrollbar when the browser width is below the width of .content (960px). 

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yeah after rereading the question i noticed that. Did you try changing it in just overflow instead of overflow-x ? overflow-x is CSS3 and maybe your browser cant handle that ?

Comment: Yeah I did, the results created no change. However, I'm using the latest build of chrome so a lack of CSS3 support wouldn't be my problem.

I've added a picture example to the top of my post for more clarity.

Comment: Can't answer my own question so I'm posting this here:

After dissecting Apple's homepage I restructued my CSS so the parent div could support:

    .content{
         width:100%;
         overflow:hidden;
         }

Problem solved.

Comment: Normally you can answer your own question :p And it's nice that you solved your own question ^^